# conversion from matlab to python of repmat

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

I want to convert the given matlab code to python

```
img_o = repmat(fill_value, osize);
```

here fill_value is a `1x1x3` matrix and  `osize=[320 320]`
output matrix is `320x320x3`

I have tried

```
img_o = tile(fill_value, osize)
```

where

```
fill_value = numpy.array([[[0, 0, 0]]])
osize=[320,320]
```

here i am getting a matrix of `1x320x960` instead of `320x320x3 matrix`
please help to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy does some nonintuitive stuff that it nonintuitively calls "broadcasting". Here's what you need (just one more explicit dimension on your size vector):

```
>>> osize = (320, 320, 1)
>>> img_o = numpy.tile(fill_value, osize)
>>> img_o.shape
(320, 320, 3)
```