# python program to replicate the given matrix

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I have a `1x1x3` matrix `A`, and a 2-element array `s= [m, n]`

i need `m-by-n` tiling of copies of `A`. so expected output is `mxnx3 matrix`.
Help me to find the correct function for the desired output.

Comment: Illustrating your question with a small example usually makes it easier to understand what you are trying to accomplish - thus it improves your chance of getting a good answer (quickly).

Comment: Isn't this pretty much the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15802430/1191119) that you posted one hour before (and was marked as a duplicate)? The answer is also like the one you accepted in the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let the 1x1x3 matrix

```
A =numpy.array([[[0, 0, 0]]])
```

and `m= 3` and `n= 3`
then to get the `mxnx3` matrix using tile

```
>>> a=tile((numpy.array([[[0, 0, 0]]])),(3,3,1))
>>> resol_val1 = a.shape
>>> resol_val1 
(3, 3, 3)
>>> a
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer as the best answer.